# AngularJS: Is it possible for the following URL to be used in a form?

Tags: html, angularjs

In a form for an AngularJS page, is it possible to use the following URL to be set for a method?

```
https://example.com/transaction-address/id3
```

I've tried doing this, but the email id I've set is not being passed. The form is being handled in the injected script and the problem (or maybe a mistake) is in the line that injects the 'id3' method.

In the script for the ng-app, I've set the 'id3' method:

```
angular.module('app', []) 
    .factory('Account', function($q, $u, $sce) { 
        $q.all([ 
            ['$http', 
            {'id1': 1, 
            'id2': 2, 
            'id3': 3, 
            'id4': 4,} 
        ]).then(function (response) { 
            var sl = 'id3'; 
            $sce.trustAsResource('id3', sl); 
            response.end(); 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to *automatize* the `id3` string here. Just assign it to a variable:

```
angular.module('app', []) 
    .factory('Account', function($q, $u, $sce) { 
        $q.all([ 
            ['$http', 
            {'id1': 1, 
            'id2': 2, 
            'id3': 3, 
            'id4': 4,} 
        ]).then(function (response) { 
            var sl = 'id3'; 
            response.sendValue(sl); 
            }) 
    });
```